# java- how to stop a robot autoclicker after one click?

Tags: java, awtrobot

I'm making an autoclicker robot in java with this code below and its worked, but i need it to click just one time and stop, please help! Thanks so much! :D

```
 try {
     Robot robot = new Robot();
     while (true) {
        try {
           Thread.sleep(5000);
           robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK);
           robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK);

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
     }
  } catch (AWTException e) {}
```

Comment: Remove the `while(true)` loop?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you so much (Y)